# Add data slice (i.e. n-by-n matrix) to multidimensional matrix in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

As per the title, is there a way to append a data slice, which is an n-by-n matrix to an existing N-dimensional matrix in R?

For example, I have the following:

```
one <- array(1, dim = c(3, 3))
two <- array(2, dim = c(3, 3))
three <- array(3, dim = c(6, 6))
```

Which I would then like to have transformed into a 6x6x3 matrix that I can work with, which would look like the following:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1    1    1   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    1    1   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    2    2    2   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[4,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[5,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
[6,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

I know how to do this via my own code, so I'm more interested in if there is an existing library function that supports this.

Comment: It's not clear, to me at least, how you want the transformation to happen.  Your data has 54 data points, but your desired matrix has 108.  So somewhere you need to pad with NAs or similar.  What are your expected results?

Comment: @Andrie - The data sets have a tendency to change over time so want I would like is for the existing data to have rows or columns added as needed and then for the new data set to be added. Eventually when this is all done it is collapsed down to a single matrix on the basis of the median so have an NA back fill missing data is fine. The big issue is performance though.

Comment: I suggest you post your code in the question so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: I think you may be looking for `abind` (in its own `abind` package), but like @Andrie I'm still confused by the question. An alternative to showing us the code would be to show us precisely what you want the output to look like.

Comment: @Andrie, @Ben Bolker - I've added some sample output to give you an idea as to what I would like the output to look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to `abind`, I guess you need to figure out the maximum size of your matrices and create matrices padded with the appropriate number of NAs?

```
padmat <- function(X,m,n) {
  Y <- matrix(NA,m,n)
  Y[1:nrow(X),1:ncol(X)] <- X
  Y
}
one <- array(1, dim = c(3, 3))
two <- array(2, dim = c(3, 3))
three <- array(3, dim = c(6, 6))

mlist <- list(one,two,three)

maxrows <- max(sapply(mlist,nrow))
maxcols <- max(sapply(mlist,ncol))

mlist2 <- lapply(mlist,padmat,m=maxrows,n=maxcols)

library(abind)
abind(mlist2,along=3)
```

Comment: That is pretty close to exactly what I'm looking for; however, right now I'm getting the the following error from `abind`: `Error in abind(mlist2, along = 3) : arg 'X3' has dims=6, 6, 1; but need dims=3, 3, X`

Comment: Ben's code works for me; are you sure you ran the `lapply` with `padmat`; that's the code that expands the matrices from 3x3 to 6x6.

Comment: @Aaron - I went back and redid the code at the console and it looks like I made a mistake the first time around, the example works perfectly and looks like what I need.